# MySQL Trigger how to update finished_date with current_timestamp when item quantity gets 0

Tags: mysql, triggers

**MySQL Trigger how to update finished_date in items table with current_timestamp when item quantity gets 0.**

**i  have tried the following trigger but is not properly working. is any one help me please**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `quantityTrigger` AFTER change ON `items.finished` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE items i
IF(i.quantity = 0) THEN
SET i.finished_date= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(Date)
 WHERE i.item_id=NEW.item_id;
  END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: is your code working? Give the exact flow. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Update command to execute in this `UPDATE ON` if you are working on the same table itself.

Do it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER quantityTrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON items FOR EACH ROW
begin

  IF(new.quantity = 0) THEN
    new.finished_date = now();
  END IF;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Just change `BEFORE` UPDATE ON or `AFTER` UPDATE ON  to simulate the problem.